# Need a information with respect to framework in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am new to selenium and using selenium webdriver to automate my current project, and I have query that is it possible to write or combine the keyword driven framework and the TestNg framework using selenium webdriver ( java)
If yes can anyone please help me with how I can approach. 
If no ,how can I validate if the test have been executed i.e passed or failed.
Please can anyone help me with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sounds like you want to use JBehave for the keyword framework.  Then, you use TestNG as a test runner and report generator.   As an alternative to that , you could use TestNG with Fitnesse, which also produces really nice reports.